# Palavra cruzada funcionando em dispositivos diferentes

Tags: android

Qual o melhor jeito de fazer um palavra cruzada de forma que rode corretamente em dispositivos diferentes?

Eu fiz os quadrados individualmente sendo cada um uma `textview` com um fundo, pois estes quadrados variam na cor de suas bordas, no caso o background, deste jeito ficou perfeito no meu celular S3 mini, porém quando rodo em outro dispositivos não ficam alinhados corretamente.

Já pesquisei e vi que eu teria que colocar imagens para os backgrounds em tamanhos diferentes no resource mas mesmo assim não ficou muito legal. O que eu poderia fazer?

segue uma parte do layout pois não deu tudo, desculpem pelos erros ainda estouf azendo alguns testes e outras coisas é por falta de experiência mesmo, obrigado

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Escolha um dos quadrados"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/quadrados"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="8" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/back_black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="wordRip"
        android:tag="1"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/back_black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="wordRip"
        android:tag="1"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/back_black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="wordRip"
        android:tag="1"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/back_fullblack"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:tag="1"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="04"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/back_black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="wordRede"
        android:tag="1"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/back_black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="wordEstrela"
        android:tag="1"
        android:textSize="21sp" />
```

Comment: Poderia incluir seu layout? Ou como esta contruindo? A quantidade de células é flexível?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/3kzz7zlg9/

Comment: a quantidade seria fixa !

Comment: Acho que usar sprites como em um jogo propriamente dito ajuda a fazer um sistema que rode na maior quantidade possível de dispositivos.

Comment: meu problema é em relacção ao dimensionamento desses quadrados que estão ficando menores do que deviam em dispositivos maiores e não sei como resolver

Comment: Se puder, coloque o xml que usa pra montar seu Layout.

Comment: editei la com parte do xml